How to get specific information from a website
I have to make a database with names and emails from a website, but there are millions of them. In order to obtain the data first I need to access the website, then clic on a button that addresses me to a different page and in that page is where I can find the information I need.
I tried to made a python script in where first I obtain the urls from each button, then, I told python to get name and email from that url. I used the class name for each container, and i asked python to create for me a .txt file with the names and emails it didn't work, the file is empty.
import requests
your text`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# WEBSITE URL
url = "https://www.bhhs.com/agent-search-results"

# HTTP REQUEST
response = requests.get(url)

# IF REQUEST SUCCESFUL, THEN:
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parsear el contenido HTML de la página
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Encontrar todos los elementos con la clase 'cmp-cta' que contienen href
    enlaces = soup.find_all('a', class_='cmp-cta')

    correos = []

    # Extraer los href de cada enlace y realizar una nueva solicitud
    for enlace in enlaces:
        href = enlace.get('href')
        if href:
            # Realizar la solicitud a cada enlace
            sub_response = requests.get(href)
            if sub_response.status_code == 200:
                sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_response.text, 'html.parser')
                # Encontrar el elemento con la clase 'cmp-agent-details__mail text-lowercase'
                correo_elemento = sub_soup.find('div', class_='cmp-agent-details__mail text-lowercase')
                if correo_elemento:
                    correo = correo_elemento.text.strip()
                    correos.append(correo)
                    print(f"Correo encontrado: {correo}")
            else:
                print(f"Error al acceder a la URL {href}: {sub_response.status_code}")

    # Guardar los correos en un archivo de texto
    with open('correos.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for correo in correos:
            file.write(f"{correo}\n")

    print("Extracción completada y datos guardados en 'correos.txt'.")
else:
    print(f"Error en la solicitud: {response.status_code}")


On the website you're scraping, is the data you want present in the Elements or the Sources tab in the Dev Tools? Elements is what the browser has rendered, Sources is what was sent to your browser, and is what requests will see. If it's only in Elements, you'll need a solution that can run JavaScript, like Selenium.

Print out your in a file the response HTML you get from requests.get. Check if the data is contained. So you can narrow down if the failure happens when retrieving the HTML or later when processing the result.

First, please tell us from where you will execute this process so we can block it, just in case you decide to scrape our web sites and arrange for the data to be used by spammers.

Is in Elements. Thanks!
